# Converting an equation to code

Tags: vb.net

I have an equation that can be used to find the gun elevation for artillery, using the range, muzzle velocity and change in altitude in a game called Arma 3. The equation looks like this:[image]

With g being the acceleration due to gravity (9.80665), V being the muzzle velocity, X being the range and Y being the change in altitude (called DAlt in my code).

I'm trying to convert it to a line of code so that I can make a program to calculate the elevation based on given coordinates. However I'm having trouble with it. I currently have this:

```
If rdoLow.Checked = True Then
    Elevation = Math.Atan(((Velocity ^ 2) - (Math.Sqrt((Velocity ^ 4) - (G) * (G * (Range ^ 2) + (2 * DAlt * (Velocity ^ 2)))))) / G * Range)
Else
    Elevation = Math.Atan(((Velocity ^ 2) + (Math.Sqrt((Velocity ^ 4) - (G) * (G * (Range ^ 2) + 2 * DAlt * (Velocity ^ 2))))) / G * Range)
End If
```

Which isn't particularly nice looking but as far as I can tell, it should work. However when I put in the values that the video I got the equation from used, I got a different answer. So there must be something wrong with my equation.

I've tried breaking it in to various parts as separate variables and calculating them, then using those variables in the overall equation, and that still didn't work and gave me an answer that was wrong in another way.

So I'm currently at a loss on how to fix it, starting to wonder if the way that vb handles long equations is different or something.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given any sample data, so I can't verify that this gives the correct answer, but the last part of your equation is missing some parentheses.

```
Elevation = Math.Atan(((Velocity ^ 2) + Math.Sqrt((Velocity ^ 4) - (G * ((G * (Range ^ 2)) + (2 * DAlt * (Velocity ^ 2)))))) / (G * Range))
```

Note the parenthesis around the last `G * Range`.

Multiplication and division have equal precedence, so they are evaluated from left-to-right. See [Operator Precedence in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw84t893.aspx).

You were dividing everything by `G`, then multiplying the result by `Range`, whereas you needed to multiply `G` by `Range`, then divide everything by the result of that.

You can see the difference in this simple example:

```
Console.WriteLine(3 / 4 * 5)    ' Prints 3.75
Console.WriteLine(3 / (4 * 5))  ' Prints 0.15
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I assumed that I was missing some parenthesis somewhere but going through it all was a nightmare, I tried numerous times to work it out and couldn't. This outputs the answer in radians correct? To convert to degrees I would say elevation = (all of that) * (math.pi/180) right?

Comment: My bad, I got it the wrong way around. Radians > degrees is 180/pi. The program seems to be working now. Using the same values as the video, my program gave 60.22 deg, while the video gave 61.06 deg. I don't see why it would be different, but this is close enough. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @thirdwaffle - Sample data provided in my answer.

Comment: From the page you linked to: *Operators with equal precedence are evaluated **left to right** in the order in which they appear in the expression.*

Comment: @Heinzi Oops, got my lefts and rights mixed up. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity I tried the problem.  In order to have test data I found this web site, [Range Tables For Mortars](https://forums.bistudio.com/topic/170255-range-tables-for-mortars/).  I tested with the '82mm Mortar - Far' that has an initial velocity of 200 m/s.  One problem I had, and don't know if I fixed it correctly, was that the first part of the equation was returning negative numbers...  I also solved for the ±.  To test I created a form with a button to perform the calculation, a textbox to enter the distance, and two labels to show the angles.  This is what I came up with.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'A - launch angle 
    'Target
    '  r - range
    '  y - altitude
    'g - gravity 9.80665 m/s^2
    'v - launch speed e.g. 50 m/s
    '
    '
    'Formula 
    'from - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile#Angle_required_to_hit_coordinate_.28x.2Cy.29
    'in parts
    'parts - px 
    ' p1 = sqrt( v^4 - g * (g * r^2 + 2 * y * v^2) )
    ' p2 = v^2 ± p1 note plus / minus
    ' p3 = p2 / g * r
    ' 
    ' A = arctan(p3)
    Dim Ap, Am, r, y As Double
    Dim g As Double = 9.80665
    Dim v As Double
    Dim p1, p2p, p2m, p3p, p3m As Double

    If Not Double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, r) Then Exit Sub

    y = 0
    v = 200 '82mm Mortar - Far velocity 
    p1 = v ^ 4 - g * (g * r ^ 2 + 2 * y * v ^ 2)
    If p1 < 0 Then
        Debug.WriteLine(p1)
        p1 = Math.Abs(p1) 'square root does not like negative numbers
    End If
    p1 = Math.Sqrt(p1)

    'plus / minus
    p2p = v ^ 2 + p1
    p2m = v ^ 2 - p1
    p3p = p2p / (g * r)
    p3m = p2m / (g * r)

    Const radiansToDegrees As Double = 180 / Math.PI

    Ap = Math.Atan(p3p) * radiansToDegrees
    Am = Math.Atan(p3m) * radiansToDegrees
    Label1.Text = Ap.ToString("n3")
    Label2.Text = Am.ToString("n3")
End Sub
```

Using the web site to verify the calculations the code seem correct.

Writing long formulas in a bunch of nested parentheses serves no purpose, unless you are going for confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I didn't really expect writing the equation in one long line would have any benefit, it's just that at the time that was the best way I had. When I tried splitting it up like you did I got answers that were wrong in another way. I may try converting it to the way you did it, just to make it easier to read. The video I got the equation from was [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4SPene9Yxw) and it would probably be easy to make a simple spreadsheet that could calculate it. But I was just looking for an excuse to practice my programming.

Comment: @DatBrummie - sorry, didn't mean to be harsh.  Do convert it and if you have problems ask for help again.